# Fancy table of tables

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create something similar, but not identical to, [this table](http://math150.net/sincos.pdf).  That is, I want to have one page-size table (two columns), and then within each cell be able to have additional tables, graphics, pgfplots, etc.  Any packages/samples to get me started?

Comment: I think it would be best done, not as a table, but as unnumbered (or not) *sections* in a two columns environment and a special formatting.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing, just  a tabular, but you can try this

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}}
\hline 
\parbox[t][\textheight][t]{\hsize}{test}& \parbox[t][\textheight][t]{\hsize}{test} \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```